# Bamboo build should fail if testng unit test case failed

Tags: unit-testing, testng, bamboo

I am trying to run a bamboo build which includes a batch script to run the testng test suit. out of 6 test suits 4 are passed and 2 getting failed. but after the build I am getting build as successful. I wanted to get the build as failed if any of the tests in the test suits failed. can any one tell me how can I configure this?

Comment: Which testing framework, test runner you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your test suite fails, does it return a negative code?

One possible solution is, use a wrapper script to check the status of your suite and return different status code so that Bamboo will catch it.

Depending on how your test suites runs you can use something as simple as a shell script.